# displaying suggestion toolbar above ios keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am a newbie in iOS development. I am trying to create a spell suggestion type application in ios 5.1 having a textView such that if user taps on a key of the keyboard a suggestion toolbar come at the top of the keyboard containing all the suggestions and if user taps onto one of those suggestions it will be displayed on the textView .

Like the one shown in figure.

[image]

I have handled the keyboard press event and handled all processing over there. Now what i want to do is that i have a NSArray of suggestions and I want to create a suggestion toolbar and assign all those suggestion from NSArray to  that toolbar and also if user taps on any of those suggestion it should be placed on the textView.

I am unable to understand how should i proceed with that and which component should i use to create that toobar above the keyboard.

using IOS SDK 5.1 and xcode 4.3

Answer (score 3):

You can make a view stick to the top of the keyboard by making it the `inputAccessoryView` for whichever text editing controls (`UITextField`, `UITextView`, etc) you want it to appear with. See the [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) protocol docs for details.

If you're not sure where to start on making a view showing words which can be tapped, you might want to look at the [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) or a good intro-to-iOS-programming book.

Answer (score 1):

You can use accessory view of keyboard to achieve this, check out this developer same code- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html