# How can I add a toolbar above the keyboard?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitoolbar

I have created a `UIToolBar` programmatically and added a `UITextField` on it. Now, I need that toolbar to be above the keyboard when I click in another text field.

```
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,400, 320, 60)];
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];

UITextField *txtView=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 260, 30)];
txtView.backgroundColor =[UIColor  grayColor];
txtView.placeholder=@"Address";
UIBarButtonItem *txtfieldItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:txtView];
toolBar.items =[NSArray arrayWithObject:txtfieldItem];
```

Comment: you already have the answer here. plz check into it... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10594891/3615320

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get keyboard with Next, Previous and Done Button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591792/how-to-get-keyboard-with-next-previous-and-done-button)

Comment: textField.inputAccessoryView = yourToolBar;

Comment: There is a newer way to do it than using a UIToolBar, http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-add-your-own-shortcuts-above-the-keyboard-in-ios-9/

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                               [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                               [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                               nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
phonenumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

To Dismiss Keyboard:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

---

Swift 3:

```
let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 50))
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
numberToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelNumberPad"),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneWithNumberPad")]
    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
    phonenumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
```

Swift 4.2:

```
let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
numberToolbar.barStyle = .default
numberToolbar.items = [
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelNumberPad)),
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneWithNumberPad))]
numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
phonenumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar

...

@objc func cancelNumberPad() {
    //Cancel with number pad
}
@objc func doneWithNumberPad() {
    //Done with number pad
}
```

Comment: Or it can be done using storyboard like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41546987/1151916)

Comment: you can add this to all textfields by doing `UITextField.appearance().inputAccessoryView = /* your tool bar setup code */`

Comment: in swift 4 selector should be like this:             UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.OnTapDone(_:)))

Comment: Toolbar width should be set based on screen-size not view-size, editing that in now along with a method to dismiss keyboard

Answer (score 107):

You do not need to do this in code anymore.

1. Just simply drag UIView to the top bar of current scene and customize it as you want.

[image]

2. In code simply put `IBOutlet` for both: `toolbarView` and `textView` and make connections.

   ```
   @IBOutlet private var toolbarView: UIView!
   @IBOutlet private var textView: UITextView!
   ```
3. In `viewDidLoad` setup your toolbarView as accessoryView of your `UItextView`.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       textView.inputAccessoryView = toolbarView
   }
   ```

The result is following:

[image]
[image]

Comment: for alertView input text you can use this: alert.textFields?.first?.inputAccessoryView = toolbarView

Comment: This is really great :) useful for textfields too.

Answer (score 21):

For swift (1.2):

```
let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

numberToolbar.items = [
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "keyboardCancelButtonTapped:"),
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "keyboardDoneButtonTapped:")]

numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
```

Answer (score 9):

You Can Use this code it work for me.

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
 UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
 [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit]; 
 UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(doneClicked:)];
  [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];
  textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
 }
-(void)doneClicked:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Done Clicked.");
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `UITextField`s ***inputAccessoryView*** property

```
    txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3

```
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(test2)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(test1))]
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0** and above

```
           let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                                  y: 0.0,
                                                  width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                                  height: 44.0))//1
            let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)//2
            let DoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: #selector(tapDone))//3
            toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpace, DoneButton], animated: false)
           textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
       // Done Action
        @objc func tapDone() {
           self.view.endEditing(true)
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textField.inputAccessoryView=[weakSelf addToolBar];
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

and add a method

```
-(UIToolbar *)addToolBar
{

    UIBarButtonItem *done=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"DONE" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    NSArray* toolBarItems=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:done, nil];
    [toolBar setItems:toolBarItems];
    return toolBar;
}
```

Comment: The first part is add the toolbar in the top of keyboard. and second is created toolbar

Comment: Thank you for interesting in ios

Comment: @DURGESHKUMAR Can you please explain this line? textField.inputAccessoryView=[weakSelf addToolBar];

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3 and 4

```
 let toolBar = UIToolbar()
 toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
 toolBar.isTranslucent = true
 toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 toolBar.sizeToFit()
 toolBar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.sendCodeBtnAction(sender:)))]

    tfPhone.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```