# Hide my decimal pad when touching another interactive component

Tags: ios, swift

I have a decimal pad that appears after I pressed a UIButton.

I have overridden `touchesBegan` method like the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

It works fine as long as for example I don't press another `UIButton` for example.

My question: is there a way to make my decimal pad disappear other than to make it disappear when I am handling the other `UIButton`'s action? Like if I have 10 other `UIButton`, it would be a bit annoying to specify every time "of by the way, before you execute your code, check if by any chance the decimal pad is hidden or not"

Comment: do it using a tap recognizer. in its delegate you can exclude specific areas, e.g. buttons.

Comment: Could you please tell me more? Where should I add the tap recognizer?

Comment: Looks similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-uitextfield

Comment: Seems to do the trick indeed. Thanks!

Comment: No actually I spoke too quickly, it doesn't work (on my `UISegmentedControl` or on my ``UIButton`)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the DecimalPad for?  If you are entering details in a text box the following will dismiss the keyboard (You will need to make your class a delegate of UITextField)

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

(objective c, not familiar with Swift notation)

Comment: Yes I do it as well but it doesn't work if I click on a button or a segment control. What do you mean what I use it for? I need it to input some numbers.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - there is no return key on a numeric keypad. have a look at this post which shows how to add a toolbar above the keyboard, so you can add your own 'Done' button to dismiss the keyboard [how-to-add-toolbar-above-keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-to-add-toolbar-above-keyboard)

Comment: I did add a return key already. I want to be able to dismiss it by clicking anywhere else as well