# Swift UIView autolayout and constraints

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I have created toolbarview top of the keyboard. I added UIView drag and drop on ViewController topside like below Image

[image]
Here, iPhone X I can see perfect size width, but if I run other devices width changing. so toolbarview showing half size of width, not showing perfect width. How to set auto layout and constraints for this. How to fix this?

Comment: if you could drag and drop to add it, you can also pin it in storyboard

Comment: how to do that? Sorry I can't get you @Lu_

Comment: Show us the constraints you applied to `Tool Bar` in Interface Builder

Comment: did you use storyboard ever before? you can search stack overflow for storyboard constraints

Comment: I didn't applied constraints for Tool Bar view. Thats my question how to do that, because its out of the iPhone frame ViewController right, so how to set constraints. please check above my all images. @zaitsman

Comment: @Lu_ Please understand my question. the tool bar view out of the iPhone viewcontroller frame, So how to do constraints. If I click tool bar view and check the add new constraints popup, its all not editable.

Comment: you didn't show any code, there is no screenshots from visual debugger, it is hard to understand question like that

Comment: Please read this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: @Lu_ I already added Images. Here, nothing to show code. Just I want to know how to set constraints for above mention toolbar view. Thats it.

Comment: @BenDev how do you make this view appear above the keyboard without adding it to your viewcontroller? never heard of that before like that.

Comment: @zaitsman please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-can-i-add-a-toolbar-above-the-keyboard/23904935#23904935

Comment: @BenDev so you have code, you can set the constraints in code then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I added view just like you**

[image]

**with constraints**

[image]

**Added this view as `inputAccessoryView`**

```
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = viewAccessory
```

**And its working fine**

[image]

---

> **Edit - ToolBar as InputAccesory**

You can achieve this with toolbar (w/o any constraint headache). Check below steps.

Select a toolbar like below and add this tool bar is place of your view.

[image]

[image]

Now add buttons like shown in above image by dragging and dropping `UIBarButtonItem` and assign images each BarButton. To make it flexible width and equally distributed just add `Flexible Space Bar Button Item`.

[image]

Now your toolbar hierarchy should be like below

[image]

And in your code

```
@IBOutlet var toolBarAccessory: UIToolbar!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextField.delegate = self
    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarAccessory

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: wow. this is I am expected. I have same like this but not working anyway I am dong double check, I will add my constraint screen. thanks man

Comment: please check above updated my question. still its not working. Please let me know if I did anything mistakes.

Comment: @BenDev Check updated answer. You dont need any single constraint. If you wanted to try new update then go with it.