# How to customize keyboard completion in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uikit

In my iOS app, I want to display existing tags as a completion on the keyboard, like Apple's Note app.

Image:

[image: (image)]

How can I implement this? Is there an API available for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a toolbar above the keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-can-i-add-a-toolbar-above-the-keyboard)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m afraid it doesn’t. That question is about the tool bar above the keyboard, but this question is on accessing the keyboard completion.